The Chinese Remainder Theorem and the yes/no question "for this general class of Diophantine Equations, is there an algorithm to find the solution"
I have recently been doing a side project and researching if there is a deep and beautiful mathematical structure in the process of recursion itself.  My idea was: once we treat algorithms themselves as mathematical objects, what can we learn about both algorithms and their mathematical recursive structure?
My (wild?) guess is that the continued fraction of e plays an important role in what I have called "mathematical recursive structure".
My yes/no question is:
(1) "for the general class of Diophantine equations with positive coefficients, is it possible to write an algorithm which produces the solution of any Diophantine equation in this class?"
I believe the answer is: no, in the general case no such algorithm can exist, and the reason for this depends essentially on questions related to continuity. I arrived at this idea from considering the class of polynomials with rational coefficients and demanding only rational number solutions.  I can further explain my reason for believing this but for brevity am omitting the details.
But what about the Chinese Remainder Theorem?  My idea is: what if represent rational numbers as repeating decimal binary expansions, and really ask ourselves the question:
"Did Qiaochu Yuan answer a 4th question in a post where I asked two questions and he gave three answers over thirteen years ago?"
The post in question is [1], I will briefly quote the relevant passage now:

The answer to question 3 is the following.


Lemma: If $n, m$ are relatively prime odd numbers, then $\text{ord}_{mn}(2) = \text{lcm}(\text{ord}_n(2), \text{ord}_m(2))$.


Proof. $\text{ord}_{mn}(2)$ is the order of the element $2$ in the multiplicative group of $\mathbb{Z}/mn\mathbb{Z}$, which we will denote $U(mn)$.  By the Chinese remainder theorem, $U(mn)$ is isomorphic to the direct product $U(m) \times U(n)$, so the order of $2$ in $U(mn)$ must be the $\text{lcm}$ of the orders of $2$ in $U(m)$ and $U(n)$.

Given that I am myself ultimately still an amateur mathematician (I am a computer programmer), I am starting to reach the limits of being able to have all the heavy machinery to answer the types of questions I am encountering.
Question: is there a strong reason to believe the Chinese Remainder Theorem may play an important role in answering the question (1) which I have posed.
Thanks!
[1] On the binary expansion of the reciprocals of prime numbers

A hurdle: "an algorithm which produces the solution" is infeasible for many Diophantine equation (systems), especially the ones having infinitely many solutions.  Every computably enumerable set is the solution set of a Diophantine system and the "generic behaviour" of such sets is that they're infinite.  Maybe requiring positive coefficients changes this, but no one seems to have published this claim.

@EricTowers thats fascinating, and good to know.  Thanks!

I just wanted to leave a quick note that the reason for posing the question about positive coefficients is this makes the problem decidable with the PIT algorithm.  whats fascinating to me is:  if its decidable but no algorithm can produce the solution, then how can we verify that the problem is decidable in the first place?  I know we can I just mean thats very interesting.

So there are three broad classes of proofs that one should attempt on a problem class: existence of solutions, uniqueness of solutions, and computation of solutions.  Just because an existence proof exists does not mean a computation method exists.  I.e., decidability only requires one bit of output but the computation may require infinite output.
